# Android - Dropbox Datastore is "empty" until application restarts

Tags: java, android, dropbox, dropbox-api

When I sign in on my application and try to get the size from the datastore's table, it is empty. But after I restart the application, it works as it should and gives back the size of the datastore's table.

In my case, there are two activities. The activity, and in-turn the fragment, SettingsFragment.java has the sign-in part. The activity MainActivity.java has the part with getting the datastore's table size.

SettingsFragment.java (Sign-in).

```
// Dropbox Signin
mAccountManager = DbxAccountManager.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), APP_KEY, SECRET_KEY);

mDropBoxPreference = findPreference("preference_sync_dbx");
mDropBoxPreference.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
        if (mAccountManager.hasLinkedAccount()) {
            mAccountManager.unlink();
        } else {
            mAccountManager.startLink(getActivity(), REQUEST_LINK_TO_DBX);
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

MainActivity.java (Get datastore size).

```
// Dropbox Get Datastore Size
mAccountManager = DbxAccountManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext(), APP_KEY, SECRET_KEY);

if (mAccountManager.hasLinkedAccount()) {
    DbxAccount mDbxAccount = mAccountManager.getLinkedAccount();
    try {
        mDbxStore = DbxDatastore.openDefault(mDbxAccount);

        mDbxNotesTable = mDbxStore.getTable("notes");
        mDbxNotesCount = mDbxNotesTable.query().count();
        Log.e("mDbxNotesCount", Integer.toString(mDbxNotesCount));
    } catch (DbxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Let's say there are 3 records in the datastore.
After I sign in, this shows up from the Logcat.

```
E/mDbxNotesCount﹕ 0
```

Once I restart it, this shows up from the Logcat.

```
E/mDbxNotesCount﹕ 3
```

What's causing it to work like this?

Edit: Added listener after using smarx's answer, and it works! Here is what I did.

```
mDbxStore.addSyncStatusListener(new DbxDatastore.SyncStatusListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDatastoreStatusChange(DbxDatastore dbxDatastore) {
        if (!dbxDatastore.getSyncStatus().isDownloading) {
            try {
                mDbxStore.sync();
                mDbxNotesCount = mDbxNotesTable.query().count();
            } catch (DbxException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.e("mDbxNotesCount", Integer.toString(mDbxNotesCount));
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Wasted couple of hours finding the solution. >_<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to read the contents of the datastore before it's had a chance to sync. You'll need to wait until the initial sync is completed. I think one way to do that would be to add a listener via `addSyncStatusListener` and wait for `store.getSyncStatus().isDownloading` to be false.

But typically the pattern you'll want to follow is to always show the current information... so set up a listener and update your UI any time it changes. That way whether it's the initial sync bringing in new records or updates from a different device, your app will respond appropriately when the information changes.